# Ошибка: expected ')' before '(' token`

Tags: qt

Здравствуйте. Работаю с записью `Exif` данных в изображения, для этого установил библиотеку `ImageMagick`. В файл проекта прописал пути к библиотеке и заголовочникам. Прописываю необходимый `include` и получаю сообщение об ошибке: 
`c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.0\..\..\..\..\include\math.h:638: ошибка: expected ')' before '(' token`.

В `math.h` в строке 638 написано: `extern double __cdecl nearbyint ( double);`. Вроде все как надо и проблем быть не должно. Подскажите, с чем может быть проблема?

Среда QtCreator 1.2.1, Qt 4.8, MinGW,  Win7 32 bit.

Не проходите мимо, пожалуйста, у меня курсовая уже 3 недели не движется.

**Добавлено.**

Место, где включаю заголовочник:

```
#include <QList>
#include <Magick++.h>
using namespace Magick;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{...}
```

Место на которое ругается в math.h:

```
/* 7.12.9.2 Double in C89 */

extern float __cdecl floorf (float);

extern long double __cdecl floorl (long double);

/* 7.12.9.3 */

extern double __cdecl nearbyint ( double);

extern float __cdecl nearbyintf (float);

extern long double __cdecl nearbyintl (long double);

/* 7.12.9.4 */

/* round, using fpu control word settings */

extern double __cdecl rint (double);

extern float __cdecl rintf (float);

extern long double __cdecl rintl (long double);
```

Или даже так. Создаю пустой Qt проект. В pro-файле пишу пути к либам. В main вот что:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "qmlapplicationviewer.h"
#include <Magick++.h>

Q_DECL_EXPORT int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QScopedPointer<QApplication> app(createApplication(argc, argv));
    QmlApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setOrientation(QmlApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationAuto);
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("qml/qttes/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();
    return app->exec();
}
```

Comment: В коде вашей программы все ок?

Comment: А отрывок кода можно увидеть? Чтобы ситуация повторялась...

Comment: @shchitov i686-w64-mingw32-g++ (GCC) 4.6.3. Компиляция прошла нормально, либы не указывал, соответственно сборка не прошла

    /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++ mag.c++ -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -I/usr/share/qtcreator/templates/qtquickapp/qmlapplicationviewer

Вообще впечатление такое, что кто-то из .h файлов балуется с макроподстановками. Можно задать только препроцессирование (ключ -E ) и куче текста-результате попытаться найти эту строку из math.h ...

Comment: Попробуйте всё-таки выполнить макропроцессор, а затем -- трансляцию полученного кода (чтобы строчку с ошибкой легче искать).

Comment: Ну почему же до ручки? Возможные причины: версия g++, не поддерживающая какие-то расширения (хотя 4.4.0 -- хм), кривой .h-файл из комплекта mingw...

Comment: Это уже другая проблема. А какого именно символа оно не находит?

Comment: А, ну это вы imagemagick'овскую библиотеку не подлинковали.

Comment: Ух, ну у вас и вопросы. Ну, вы должны указать линкеру имя .lib-файла, который он будет искать в путях. Как у вас прописана команда линковки? (Вы делаете не через проект Visual Studio, а через makefile, да?) Как именно интерпретируется pro-файл, не знаю, сорри.

Comment: Не, этого мало: кроме _пути_ к lib'ам надо ещё указать, какие именно lib'ы из этих путей подлинковывать (линкер не будет пробовать все подряд, он ленивый).

Comment: Хм, а как насчёт подчёркивания в конце? Может, оно не нужно? Выглядит подозрительно.

Comment: Без подчеркивания уже не может найти либы. 

:-1: ошибка: LNK1104: cannot open file 'CORE_DB_Magick++.lib'

Comment: Но имя библиотеки указано правильно. Хм. Не понимаю. Может, вам нужно подлинковать ещё что-то?

Comment: Знать бы что...

Comment: Ну, документация на функцию или класс обязана сказать, что именно нужно подлинковать. Гляньте в неё.

Comment: В Документации сказано, что класс Image использует только STL, а он, как я понимаю, и так распознается студийным компилятором. Да и вся ImageMagick использует только STL.

Comment: Хм. Ну, использует — это да, а сами скомпилированные классы у imagemagick++ где находятся? Только в одной библиотеке, или в нескольких?

Comment: Да, в нескольких. И я пробовал их все подключать, но результат тот же.

Comment: Кстати. Разные компиляторы используют lib в разном формате. Убедитесь, что ваш lib именно для msvc (снова-таки, должно быть что-то типа readme).